# Descending chaincondition for cyclic ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

in generell I want to show that if a Ring $R$ satisfies the descending chaincondition for cyclic ideals, so every chain of cyclic ideals $(r_1)\supset (r_2)\supset \dots$ in $R$ becomes stationary, then every prime ideal is maximal.

If we take a prime ideal $\mathcal{p} \subset R$, then $R/\mathcal{p}$ is an integral domain.
For $\mathcal{p}$ to be maximal, $R/\mathcal{p}$ has to be a field.

**Now my question:** Can we show that $R/\mathcal{p}$ satisfies the descending chaincondition for cyclic ideals, if $R$ does?

In this case it would be rather easy to show that every element in $R/\mathcal{p}$ has an inverse and therefore $R/\mathcal{p}$ would be a field.

If that's not the case, then what approach could I try instead?

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than worrying about the chain condition in the quotient, one could just note that for all $a\in R$, there exist positive integers $m,n$ with $m>n$ and an element $x\in R$ such that $a^n=a^{m}x$.  This is a simple consequence of applying the descending chain condition to the chain $aR\supseteq a^2R\supseteq a^3R\supseteq\ldots$. (*)

Because you can do this in $R$, you can do it in any quotient of $R$.

Of course, in the quotients that are domains, $a$ is zero or cancels down to $1=a^{m-n}x$, proving $a$ is a unit.

(*) Rings satisfying this condition for all elements are called **strongly $\pi$-regular**. Rings satisfying the descending chain condition on principal right ideals are called **left perfect rings**.  (Yes, I do mean **left**. It is a very curious crossover characterization.)